# How to make dynamic heights for surfaces famo.us?

Tags: angularjs, famo.us

I want to create scrollView in famo.us/angularjs project, the problem is I have to specify the height of each surface as if I didn't it takes the height of the parent which is **fa-app** element, want the height to be dynamically compatible like the surfaces be relative to each other, I specified the size to be undefined but it takes the height of the parent.

```
<fa-scroll-view fa-pipe-from="myEventHandler">
 <fa-view>

   <fa-modifier fa-size="[undefined, undefined]">
      <fa-surface fa-pipe-to="myEventHandler">
       <!--content-->    
      </fa-surface>
   </fa-modifier>


   <fa-modifier fa-size="[undefined, undefined]">
      <fa-surface fa-pipe-to="myEventHandler">
       <!--content-->    
      </fa-surface>
   </fa-modifier>

 </fa-view>
</fa-scroll-view>
```

Answer (score 0):

"undefined" is using the size of its parent. "true" is the size of itself. Please try [undefined, true] instead of [undefined, undefined]